# Implementing Predictive Posterior Distribution Using Stan

Tags: r, statistics, mcmc, stan

**Background**

I had an example that sought to demonstrate the *posterior predictive distribution* in the context of a normal measurement model. The data that was used is as follows:

```
speed <- c(28, 26, 33, 24, 34, -44, 27, 16, 40, -2, 29, 22, 24, 21, 25, 30, 23, 29, 31, 19, 24, 20, 36, 32, 36, 28, 25, 21, 28, 29, 37, 25, 28, 26, 30, 32, 36, 26, 30, 22, 36, 23, 27, 27, 28, 27, 31, 27, 26, 33, 26, 32, 32, 24, 39, 28, 24, 25, 32, 25, 29, 27, 28, 29, 16, 23)
```

The Stan model provided is as follows:

```
data{
  int<lower=1> n;
  vector[n] y;
}

parameters{
  real y_mu;
  real y_lsd;
}

transformed parameters{
  real<lower=0> y_sd;
  
  y_sd = exp(y_lsd);
}

model{
  y ~ normal(y_mu, y_sd);
}

generated quantities{
  vector[n] y_rep;
  
  for(i in 1:n){
    y_rep[i] = normal_rng(y_mu, y_sd);
  }
}
```

We then call the following sampling command:

```
data.in <- list(y=speed, n=length(speed))
model.fit <- sampling(NMM_PPD, data=data.in)
```

This example demonstrated that the normal measurement model does not seem to be suitable for these data. Why? Because while the mean and median of the original data `y` are almost in centre of these statistics calculated on replicated data sets sampled from the posterior predictive distributions, this was not the case for the minimum, the maximum or the inter-quartile range. Also, the histogram of the original data set looks significantly different compared to histograms on replicated data sets from the posterior predictive distribution.
This is illustrated below.

We first use the `extract()` function to extract our replicated data sets from the `model.fit` object:

```
yrep <- extract(model.fit, pars = "y_rep")[[1]]
```

Histograms:

```
ppc_hist(speed, yrep[sample(NROW(yrep), 11), ])
```

[image]

Mean:

```
ppc_stat(speed, yrep)
```

[image]

Maximum:

```
ppc_stat(speed, yrep, stat = "max")
```

[image]

And others are calculated as follows:

```
ppc_stat(speed, yrep, stat = "median")

ppc_stat(speed, yrep, stat = "min")

stat <- function(x) diff(quantile(x, probs = c(0.25, 0.75)))
ppc_stat(speed, yrep, stat = stat)
```

**Problem**

I now want to fit the following model:

(TeX Representation)

$Y_i | \mu, \sigma \sim t_{\nu}(\mu, \sigma)$, $i = 1, \dots, n$ independent

$\mu \sim N(0, 1000^2)$

$\sigma \sim \text{Half_Cauchy}(0, 5)$

(Image Representation)

[image]

Where t represents a t random variable, and the symbol $\nu$ represents the degrees of freedom.

I want to experiment with different values of $\nu$ to see which value is appropriate for modelling the aforementioned statistics (max, mean, median, min, quantile).

My current Stan code is as follows:

```
data{
  int<lower=1> n;
  vector[n] y;
}

parameters{
  real y_mu;
  real y_sd;
  real nu;
}

model{
  y ~ student_t(nu, y_mu, y_sd);
  y_mu ~ normal(0, 1000);
  y_sd ~ cauchy(0, 5);
}

generated quantities{
  vector[n] y_rep;
  
  for(i in 1:n){
    y_rep[i] = student_t_rng(nu, y_mu, y_sd);
  }
}
```

And I draw samples from the model using the following code:

```
data.in <- list(y=speed, n=length(speed))
model.fit <- sampling(NMM_PPD, data=data.in)
```

The results are obtained as follows:

```
print(model.fit, pars = c("y_mu", "y_sd", "nu"), digits = 5)
```

[image]

So we have nu = 2.56.

However, I'm unsure if I've gone about this correctly. Is this how we obtain the value of `nu` that best fits the model?

I've been researching other Stan implementations of predictive posterior distributions, but I'm still not 100% sure that I've implemented this correctly.

https://magesblog.com/post/2015-05-19-posterior-predictive-output-with-stan/

https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/4e97/66371e7572609594a4f68fc74b7c6fe70767.pdf

https://magesblog.com/post/2015-05-19-posterior-predictive-output-with-stan/

Comment: It depends what you mean by "best fits the model".  The marginal posterior mean for a parameter (e.g., 2.56 for nu) is the point estimate that minimizes expected square error.  The marginal posterior median minimizes expected absolute error.  Neither is "best" in any sense.  Other estimates, like the posterior mode (aka max a posteriori, aka MAP), don't have these nice properties.

Comment: You also want to have a zero lower bound on the declarations of `nu` and `y_sd`.  You might want to put a larger lower bound on `nu` as a value of 1 already gives you the Cauchy distribution.

Comment: @BobCarpenter By “best fits the model”, I mean that the statistics for the original data ‘y’ closely resemble those calculated on replicated data sets from the posterior predictive distribution. See the plots I posted for mean and max.

Comment: Yes, that's the right way to generate a simulated data set.  The uncertainty in `nu` in the posterior is rolled into the posterior predictive simulations.  So it doesn't use a single value of `nu`.  It doesn't look like there was a problem in fitting the model, either.  Obviously, with the kind of bimodal (or skewed outlier) data you have, none of these unimodal models are going to fit very well.

Comment: @BobCarpenter When I constrain `nu` and `y_sd` with `<lower=0>`, I get totally different values. For instance, for `nu`, I get extremely large values like 2.467434e+14. So it seems that I need to keep the constraint <lower=0> off. It seems that setting the lower bound lower=0 on `y_sd` is not the problem — it changes nothing. The problem seems to be setting the lower bound on `nu`. Any idea why this happens?

Comment: `nu` should have a lower bound of 0 or higher as you can't have a negative number of degrees of freedom for a Student-t.  You can look at the traceplots to see what's going on.  Same for the scale parameter (it's not standard deviation for a Student-t, by the way---the standard deviation is infinite whenever `nu` is less than one.)

Comment: @BobCarpenter But then the question is, why am I getting such large values for `nu` when I set `<lower=0>` in the above code?

Comment: In the limit as nu goes to infinity, the student t approaches normality.  So data even remotely consistent with normality will be consistent with large `nu`. When I run the model with a lower bound of 0 on `nu` and `sigma`, it fails to converge and prints diagnostic warnings.  If I include sensible priors, such as normal(0, 50) for mu, normal(0, 50) for nu, and cauchy(0, 10) for sigma_y, everything behaves as you night expect.

Comment: (I assume the triple-back-tick devices were not meant to be visible here - I have hidden them).